How to register MediatR in WPF application
I'm experimenting with DDD in an MVVM application.
It is a basic customer system.
When I add an address I want to validate it does not exist in the database.
This can be done by using a Domain Event in the Customer entitity
    public async Task<ErrorOr<Success>> AddAdress(AddAddressCommand addAddressCommand)
    {
       await DomainEvents.Raise(new AddingAddress(addAddressCommand));    

       return Result.Success;
   }

The AddAddressCommand is:
    public class AddAddressCommand
    {
        public Address Address { get; set; }
        public AddAddressCommand(Address address) 
        {
           Address = address;
        }
    }

with the following Address class:
    public record Address(AddressType AddressType,
    string StreetName, 
    string HouseNumber, 
    string HousenumberAddition, 
    string PostalCode, 
    string Residence
    ) 
    {
       public AddressType AddressType { get; set; } = AddressType;        
       public string StreetName { get; set; } = StreetName;        
       public string HouseNumber { get; set; } = HouseNumber;        
       public string HouseNumberAddition { get; set; } = HousenumberAddition;        
       public string PostalCode { get; set; } = PostalCode;        
       public string Residence { get; set; } = Residence;                
    }

I'm using MediatR to handle this kind of events using this class
    public static class DomainEvents
   {
        public static Func<IMediator> Mediator { get; set; }
        public static async Task Raise<T>(T args) where T : INotification
        {
          var mediator = Mediator.Invoke();
          await mediator.Publish<T>(args);
        }
}

When I arrive here the Mediator instance is not found!
I register the Mediator instance im my app.xaml.cs like:
ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType<IMediator, Mediator>();
ServiceLocator is part of the Catel MVVM framework.
I find numerous examples how to register MediatR, but all are Web API based.
I cannot figure out how to register MediatR properly.
The app.xaml.cs and the domainevents are in separate assemblies.
I've tried to locate the service like
    public static class DomainEvents
    {
        public static Func<IMediator> Mediator { get; set; }
        public static async Task Raise<T>(T args) where T : INotification
        {
            var mediator = ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveType<IMediator>();
            mediator = Mediator.Invoke();
            await mediator.Publish<T>(args);
         }
    }

But this still leaves with the error of IMediator not found
I supposse I need something like
ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterType<IMediator>(AddMediatR(cfg => {                cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(typeof(Program).Assembly)))}
but I cannot get this to work.

The static Func<IMediator> Mediator { get; set; } looks like a function that should be set. Is it null right now? If so, I think this should be something like () => ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveRequiredType<IMediator>();

Changed to  public static IMediator mediator => ServiceLocator.Default.ResolveRequiredType(); This now errors on 'Catel.IoC.TypeNotRegisteredExpection'

Did you put breakpoints in both app.xaml.cs (AddMediatR method) and where you set it? Make sure the registration happens before the resolving.
It might also be required that you use RegisterInstance (since you are passing in an instance).

That is the main problem, AddMediatR method uses Microsoft.Dependency injection. I can 't get it to work with Catel.ServiceCollection to register it

Changed the registration in app.xaml.cs to var config = new Mediator(ServiceLocator.Default.GetServiceLocator());
ServiceLocator.Default.RegisterInstance(config); The Mediator class is the n found but when I publish the error is "Exception thrown: 'System.InvalidOperationException' in Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll" MediatR seems to need the Microsoft Dependency Injection

It is probably impossible without adding Catel.ServiceLocator IoC support to MediatR library. I just researched a little and there are similar functions that we can transform while registering whole MediatR with AddMediatR(). I don't know will it work but it seems feasible. I think you should open an issue here MediatR Github Repo Issues
